# How can I use GLSurfaceView in a LinearLayout together with other Views, such as TextView or Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es-2.0

I'm doing a small game on Android 2.3.3 and I want to use openGLES. My question is whether I can **GLSurfaceView** and **TextView**, **Button** in the same layout. My layout xml file is as the following

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<com.ecnu.sei.manuzhang.nim.GameView
    android:id="@+id/game_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
 />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_turn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
 />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_turn"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
/>
```

When `GameView extends GLSurfaceView` there will be errors `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: GameView(Context,AttributeSet)` but `GameView extends GLSurfaceView` will do.
   If not, is there a way to put those widgets together?
  Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When extending `View` or in this case `GLSurfaceView` you might need to place the correct constructor.

In your case you are missing this one:

```
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

You can check how it's done inside [cocos2d-x](http://cocos2d-x.org) with the [Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/HelloWorld/android/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java).

Comment: this means I have to call `super(context, attrs)` ?

Comment: Nope. When you place a custom view in you xml the os will use the constructor I mentioned to create the object. You will need to have that constructor in your class.

Comment: Yeah, it works now! Thank you so much! I simply copy codes from the official dev guide but I'm curious how you figure it out in the first place

Comment: @manuzhang: It's a common mistake and it's something I forget every time I extend `View`.